# Android - Changing compileSdkVersion leads to errors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio 1.2.2 to develop an Android Application. In my build.gradle file, I have defined the `compileSdkVersion` to 21 since the beginning of the work. Now I wanted to change that to 19, since this software actually will never be installed on an Android device, that runs a higher version than Android 4.4

When I try to change this value to 19, the project does not compile anymore.

After the change of the version value I have:

- synced the project
- cleaned the project
- rebuild the project (tried)

**But the following error occurs:**

In the file `/projectpath/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml` it marks 103 errors, saying "cannot resolve symbol".

**values-v21.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/lmp-mr1-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v21/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2"/>
    <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Button"/>
....
```

- `cannot resovle symbol android:TextAppearance.Material`
- `cannot resovle symbol android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1`
- `cannot resovle symbol android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2`
- `cannot resovle symbol android:TextAppearance.Material.Button`

and so on...

**What is causing this error? What can I do to make it compile again?**
When I change back the `compileSdkVersion` to 21, everything works normal again.

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.appname.id'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.2 Alpha"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: You don't require `values-v21.xml` if you are not targeting API 21. Delete `values-v21.xml` from your project.

Comment: Thank you! This file is located under the `build`-folder. I can delete it, but it gets recreated with the same error. in my project I can't find a file called "values-v21.xml". So where does this come from?

Comment: Check @Budius's answer if it works.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use `appcompat-v7:22.2.0` you have to compile against API `21`. There's no harm in doing it, even if it will never run on devices running `21`.

You can try some older version of the app compat, but then you will be missing in "cool new features" and bug fixes from the latest app compat.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know, that it does no harm to let `compileSdkVersion` on 21. For testing i have included v4 instead of v7 of appcompat and it resolved the issue! Will leave it on 21 though.

Answer (score 1):

If this might help someone, after MANY trials and errors, I found that I was targeting the wrong SDK version (an older one) in the build.gradle file corresponding to "library". To change this you can do it by hand or go to the Module Settings Menu (right click on your project folder -> Open Module Settings. Then in "library" - Properties you can change the Compile Sdk and the Build Tools Versions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have installed API 19 in sdk manager